# In iOS app, "Member for" and "Last active" in user profile are not displayed if About Me is empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, ios-app, last-activity

I am running the StackExchange iOS app version 1.2.2.

When I viewed the following user's Puzzling profile, it displays his "Member for" and "Last active" information.  You'll notice that he has also filled in his "About Me" section.

[image]

But another user's Puzzling profile does not display the "Member for" and "Last active" information.  Unlike the previous user, he has **not** filled in his "About Me" section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will *finally* be fixed in 1.4.3.3.

Comment: Better Late than Never! (Wish I could say the same for android app...)