# Show the number of profile views in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, ios-app, views

When viewing a user's profile on a specific site in the iOS app, it will display the user's "Member for" and "Last active" information (unless you encounter the bug that I've described in [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251784/in-ios-app-member-for-and-last-active-in-user-profile-are-not-displayed-if)).

I'd like to see it display the "Profile views" in the same section that has the "Member for" and "Last active" information.

Also, why not include the Location and Age of the user as well?  Those are all displayed when you view the user's profile in a desktop browser.

Comment: This is such a simple thing to implement, I don't know why anyone would disagree with it.

Comment: @pacoverflow Maybe it is not significant enough? I don't think many people will be interested in your profile views.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 Whereever possible I'd like to see the app have the same functionality that you would have in a desktop browser.  This is something that can be easily done, so why not do it?

Comment: It is easy, but does it mean it **must** be implemented? This proposal won't do any harm, but I don't think it is that significant to be implemented. We'll wait for the devs to decide. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will be added in 1.4.3.3 between "Member for" and "Last seen" like it is on the web.